# How to debug Symfony3 with Netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, symfony, xdebug

I can't debug Symfony 3 with Netbeans.

I performed the following steps:

1) I installed php5-xdebug on ubuntu

2) I modified the php.ini file as follows:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp 
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.max_nesting_level=300
```

3) I restarted apache

4) On Netbeans I set Run Configuration->Advanced->Do not Open Web Browser

5) I installed the easy Xdebug add-on for Firefox

6) I start the application with the console command php bin/console server:start

7) I put the breakpoint on the controller action with Netbeans

8) I start debug with Netbeans

9) I go on the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/shifts/1?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug

Q - The page will load normally and debugging does not go on the breakpoint. Where am I wrong?

thanks

Comment: You're mixing Apache's httpd server (3.) with built-in php http server (6).

Comment: Ok, now I use only Apache as shown http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html. Now debug with Netbeans works, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In order to debug your application using the PHP's built-in server follow the following steps:

1. In the tab **"Projects"** right-click on the project you wish to debug.
2. In the **"Categories"** list choose **"Run Configuration"**.
3. In the **"Run As"** select box choose **"PhP Built-in Web Server (running on built in web server)"**.
4. Add your **Hostname** and **Port** and press "OK".

Done with NetBeans IDE 8.2